# Javascript in ajax call, possibly caching?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, caching

I am using some ajax to pull in new content on some pages. The content itself has a script inside it that is run and used when the content is pulled on to run some effects, click functions, and other ajax calls.

The issue I am having is - when I wipe out the old content and add in the new it seems some of the click functions from the old javascript are still running. For example I have a menu button click in within the content I pull in. When I wipe out content 1 and bring in content 2, it has the same menu button with click functionality. When I click the menu button it is both running the new javascript and the old (just replaced) javascript on it. My suspicion is it is possibly caching. Any insight on this would be greatly helpful.

Just to clarify - the content I am pulling in is new page content with html/javacript.

Comment: It depends on how your handlers are set up.  You have not posted any of that code, however, so it's hard to say.

Comment: Make sure you have caching set to false in jQuery.ajax: `$.ajax({ url : 'your.url', cache : false });`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using

```
$("#myId").on("click",function(){...
```

Try this :

```
$("#myId").off("click");
$("#myId").on("click",function(){...
```

Comment: or... if that's really the issue, move the event binding outside of the callback